# How to clear the text fields using the javascriptExecutor in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

The following code isused to clear the text box value or we can use this to clear the text box in selenium if the clear() function is not working use below code
`

```
      if (maturityDate.compareTo(currentDate)<0)
      {
          System.out.println("Maturity Date is less than today date");
          renewalMaturityDate.click();
             JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)selenium;
              js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '';", renewalMaturityDate);
              renewalMaturityDate.sendKeys(futuredate);
      }
      
      else if (maturityDate.compareTo(currentDate)>0) {
          System.out.println("Maturity Date is Greater than today date"); 
          renewalMaturityDate.click();
           JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)selenium;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '';", renewalMaturityDate);
          renewalMaturityDate.sendKeys(maturityDate);
        rm.waitForSeconds(1);           
      }
```

Comment: Are you asking for help? Or giving some solution to ... ? See ['how to ask a question'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to use JS Executor to clean InputField.

One of the solutions is using org.openqa.selenium.Keys:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE));
```

Comment: recently i am not able to clear text box value using node js web application so i found that JS Executor to clean Input Field